# How do I include a React app?

Tags: blocks

We are moving towards a hybrid-headless model with Drupal 7. All our data is exposed through RESTful and I have successfully built React app using the data.

How can pull that app in as a block? I put the code in a block and the app loses much of its styling and 1 third of the data is hidden. The basic functionality still works, but that's not enough.

Is there some trick to getting the a the full app to run correctly in a block?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this as follows:

1. install react-app-rewired:  npm i --D react-app-rewired -- 
   this is important so you don't try to load react more than once
2. change package.json so build executes react-app-rewired build -- full instructions here: https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired
3. Pick a spot in your Drupal install for your react app  -- I chose sites/all/react, it seemed right to me
4. load react into your template using the CDN links https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html
5. update package.json with homepage for your app to reflect where you are saving it for example: "homepage": "/sites/all/libraries/myapp/",
6. build your react app and copy the contents of the build folder to the location you chose for storing your app
7. build a simple module to load your app as a block (code below)
8. add the block to your page however you see fit

```
/* Adds the block to the block menu */
function my_app_block_info() {
  $blocks['my_react_app'] = array( //a new array for each new app
    'info' => t('My React App'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );

  return $blocks;
}
```

/* set the content for the block */

```
function my_app_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'my_react_app': //a new case for each new app 
        $block['content'] = file_get_contents(libraries_get_path('appfolder').'/index.html');

        break;
     }
  return $block;
}
```

```
 /* 
   file_get_contents loads the index.html page that loads 
   the react app don't use libraries_get_path if you saved your app 
   somewhere else
 */
```

Comment: Did you try [PDB](https://www.drupal.org/project/pdb) @daniel-lefebvre

Comment: Nice module, thanks :) But I am working with D7 so, there are a number of nice headless options that I don't have access to.